# SQL Conditional/Iif Where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm working on this query that shows the receivables in 2021-01. Sometimes the matchdate is before the original invoice date, in that case I want a different where clause. This is the desired where clause:

```
if status = 1 then where originalmatch_period <= 202101 else
where yearperiod <= 202101 and originalinvoice_period <= 202101
```

Can someone help me to make this work?

Comment: Can status  be null?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put it in the same clause and distinguish the case with OR:

```
WHERE (status = 1 AND originalmatch_period <= 202101) 
   OR (status <> 1 AND yearperiod <= 202101 and originalinvoice_period <= 202101)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, there are various approaches like dynamic SQL or apply all possible conditions with OR

Here are sample that may be helpful to build your solution.

**OR approach**  (please refer kutschkem's answer)

**Dynamic Query Approach:**

```
DECLARE @SelectQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM Table'
DECLARE @WhereClause NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' WHERE '

IF @status = 1 then 
BEGIN 
  SET @WhereClause =  @WhereClause + 'originalmatch_period <= 202101'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + 'yearperiod <= 202101 and originalinvoice_period <= 202101'
END

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = @SelectQuery  + @WhereClause 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the two answers are correct, if you don't want to use variables just use kutschkem solution, will be easier

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).